# How to update signature of typescript when testing with a mock

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I am using jest to mock implementation of a method with this signature

```
(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3: callback)
(arg1: string, arg3: callback)
```

and I want to invoke the arg3 directly inside my test by mockImplementation

```
func.mockImplementation((arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3: callback) => {
  const actualCallback = arg2 // we know we are using the second case here.
  actualCallback()
})
```

But typescript gives me an error. How do I skip the typescript checks when mocking function signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one of two ways.

1. You'll have to type the second parameter differently to reflect that this function combines the two previous type signatures.

```
func.mockImplementation((arg1: string, arg2: string | callback, arg3: callback) => {
  const actualCallback = arg2 as callback // Explicitly tell TS what type it is.
  actualCallback()
})
```

2. Simply ignore the error with ‘// @ts-ignore’ comment.

```
func.mockImplementation((arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3: callback) => {
  const actualCallback = arg2
  // @ts-ignore
  actualCallback()
})
```